# TypeError: expect(...).toBeObservable is not a function - Jasmine marbles

Tags: angular7, ngrx-effects, jasmine-marbles

I am trying to write a basic ngrx effects testing. However I keep getting the error as TypeError: expect(...).toBeObservable is not a function.

This is a new project setup with Angular 7. I had no issues with my previous projects which ran in angular 4.

Initially thought it could be something to do with packages so upgraded all packages to the most latest but no luck yet.

I event tried to test a very simple observable as expect(effects.test$).toBeObservable(5); but it gives the same error. As mentioned in the title I am using jasmine-marbles and the version is 0.4.1.

Comment: I guess this is caused by rxjs. since rxjs 6, it changed a lot, so I think this is the dependency version problem.

Comment: also since rxjs 6, it use pipe style operators, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md and I think you need to change your code to the pipe operators as well.

Comment: Thanks @Niuhuru Lang, I am aware of pipepable operators. What surprises me is that I just installed Angular CLI 7 globally and did ng new project. Added store and jasmine-marbles. I expect a simple observable test to pass but its not happening!

Answer (score 12):

You need to init the test scheduler and add matchers in before each or toBeObservable will not be defined:

```
import { addMatchers, initTestScheduler } from 'jasmine-marbles';

beforeEach(() => {
  ...
  initTestScheduler();
  addMatchers();
});
```

Comment: Also reported here: https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles/issues/21

Comment: I had same issue as OP. I applied your fix and now I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
` --> coming from TestScheduler.ts parseMarbles method --> marbles.indexOf('!') --> marbles are undefined.

Comment: @codeepic, you need to input an observable build by jasmin-marbles functions. This will work:

`const expected$ = cold('(a)', { a: false });
expect(result$).toBeObservable(expected$);`

While this won't
`const expected1$ = of(false);
expect(result$).toBeObservable(expected1$);`